# How can I use googleapis into react native?

Tags: node.js, react-native, google-api, google-drive-api

Currently, I am trying to use google drive API v3 into react native. I am taking as an example from google drive API v3 [Node.js](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/nodejs). But the problem is when I am trying to import the googleapis into my project it's showing below error.

[image]

I googled many times but can't find solutions. Can anybody help me out of this?

Answer (score 6):

The Node.JS API for Google Drive makes use of Node's built-in `path` module. Aside from the developer tools, [React Native is not built on top of Node](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html) - it makes use of Safari's JavaScript engine, JavaScriptCore. Therefore, when you run your application, the `path` module doesn't exist, and the API client won't work.

You instead need to make use of [the REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/) directly to communicate with Google.

Comment: You can also use a wrapper for Google Drive's API, e.g. https://github.com/RobinBobin/react-native-google-drive-api-wrapper.