# Opening gmail emails in my react native email client app

Tags: react-native, gmail-api

I am trying to integrate an email client in my app. I checked the g-mail API
documentation but I was not able to locate any material for react native apps.

Most of the questions I could find were on how to open an email client.

How can I get email data into my app and make my own email client?

(I only need it for gmail)

i have tried to use gmail API but I could not find any third party libraries for this task.

[How can I use googleapis into react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44327592/how-can-i-use-googleapis-into-react-native)